# Configure CKEditor to create an HTML <button>

Tags: html, button, input, ckeditor

Is it possible to configure the "Button" button...

[image]

...in [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) to output a proper HTML `<button>` instead of an `<input type="button">`?